# Using AWK to perform VLOOKUP-like command

Tags: awk, vlookup

I have a set of files with genotypic data, each divided into 3 columns of data, including: MARKER, ID, GENOTYPE.

I would like to use AWK (without changing the order/sorting of the files) to perform a VLOOKUP-like command in order to join the data within the files into a single file as follows:

File1:

```
BIEC2-99962 HOR_233 G_G
BIEC2-9997 HOR_233 A_G
BIEC2-999748 HOR_233 C_C
BIEC2-999848 HOR_233 G_G
BIEC2-99989 HOR_233 A_A
```

File2:

```
BIEC2-9997 HOR_250 A_A
BIEC2-999748 HOR_250 C_C
BIEC2-99989 HOR_250 A_C
```

File3:

```
BIEC2-9997 HOR_615 A_G
BIEC2-999748 HOR_615 A_C
BIEC2-999848 HOR_615 A_G
BIEC2-99989 HOR_615 A_C
```

Expected result:

```
BIEC2-99962 G_G NA NA   
BIEC2-9997 A_G A_A A_G
BIEC2-999748 C_C C_C A_C
BIEC2-999848 G_G NA A_G
BIEC2-99989 A_A A_C A_C
```

I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Posted on other sites: https://www.biostars.org/p/131688/   http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?p=160574#post160574

Comment: It is fascinating how some people assume that everyone has the same background knowledge that they do when posting a question. What EXACTLY does a `VLOOKUP-like command` do when it's at home? What EXACTLY, in words, do you want such a command to do given your input files? Edit your question to provide the answers.

Comment: I'll agree the question could have been more thought out (never heard of a VLOOKUP either) but in this case the sample input and output make it reasonably clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely trivial to insert those NA's when the existence of a marker might not even be known until the last file. Without that, this would be a one-liner.

```
#!/bin/awk

func add_na() {
  for (i in a)
    if (gsub(/ /, " ", a[i]) < files)
      a[i] = a[i] " NA"
}

FNR==1 { add_na(); ++files }

{ a[$1] = a[$1] " " $3 }

END { add_na(); for (i in a) print i a[i] }
```

The `add_na` function finds markers which haven't shown up in the latest file (i.e. have too few spaces in their output records so far) and adds an "NA" to them.
The `FNR` rule keeps track of how many files we've been through, and sorts out the NAs.
The `END` rule adds a last round of NAs before printing out the results.

Comment: Cool! (+1). Apparently the order of the files is changed.

Comment: It's the ordering of `for (index in array)` that's generally non-deterministic. The order of genotypes in each line of output will still strictly follow the order of input files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ok is not awk: I feel more comfortable with Perl when complex types are involved...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
my %out;
my $argc = scalar @ARGV;   # @ARGV --> command line arguments
for my $i (1..$argc){      # for all files except the first
  open(F,$ARGV[$i]);
  while(<F>){
    if(/(.*) .* (.*)/){$out{$1}[$i]=$2}
  }
}

open(F,$ARGV[0]);          # process the first
while(<F>){
  if(/(.*) .* (.*)/){
    $a=join(" ",map{ $out{$1}[$_] || "NA"} (1..$argc-1));
    print "$1 $2 $a\n"}
}
```

Usage:

```
perl merge-vlookup file1 file2 file3 ... >  output
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably modify this script for your input sets:

```
​#!/usr/bin/env python

input_one = '''
BIEC2-99962 HOR_233 G_G
BIEC2-9997 HOR_233 A_G
BIEC2-999748 HOR_233 C_C
BIEC2-999848 HOR_233 G_G
BIEC2-99989 HOR_233 A_A
'''.strip().split()

input_two = '''
BIEC2-9997 HOR_250 A_A
BIEC2-999748 HOR_250 C_C
BIEC2-99989 HOR_250 A_C
'''.strip().split()

input_three = '''
BIEC2-9997 HOR_615 A_G
BIEC2-999748 HOR_615 A_C
BIEC2-999848 HOR_615 A_G
BIEC2-99989 HOR_615 A_C
'''.strip().split()

one_list = input_one[::3]
one_dict = dict(zip(one_list, input_one[2::3]))
two_dict = dict(zip(input_two[::3], input_two[2::3]))
three_dict = dict(zip(input_three[::3], input_three[2::3]))

print '\n'.join([' '.join([k, one_dict[k], two_dict.get(k, 'NA'), three_dict.get(k, 'NA')]) for k in one_list])
```

The output looks like:

```
$ ./join_test.py
BIEC2-99962 G_G NA NA
BIEC2-9997 A_G A_A A_G
BIEC2-999748 C_C C_C A_C
BIEC2-999848 G_G NA A_G
BIEC2-99989 A_A A_C A_C
```

This seems to match your expected output.

If you want to understand how the script works, use some `print` statements for each variable before the list comprehension, and then break the list comprehension down into smaller pieces.

Ultimately, you would replace lists `input_one`, `input_two` and `input_three` with the results from reading in your input files with `open()` and `readlines()` methods.

Remember to `strip()` and `split()` so that each element of the list is separated from the others, regardless of whether the delimiter is a space or newline — use `print` to investigate one of the sample input lists, if this requirement isn't clear.

I'd second that `awk` is not really the ideal tool for this job, and I use it a great deal.